# C syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

Tags: c, syntax-error, visual-c++-2010

I'm getting a very strange syntax error in a C project I'm doing in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. I have the following code:

```
void LoadValues(char *s, Matrix *m){
    m->columns = numColumns(s);
    m->rows = numRows(s);
    m->data = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * (m->rows * m->columns));
    int counter = 0;
    double temp;
    bool decimal;
    int numDec;
    while(*s != '\0'){
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

When I try to Build Solution, I get the "missing ';' before type" error for all of my variables (temp, counter, etc), and trying to use any of them in the while loop causes an "undeclared identifier" error. I made sure bool was defined by doing

```
#ifndef bool
    #define bool char
    #define false ((bool)0)
    #define true ((bool)1)
#endif
```

at the top of the .c file. I've searched Stack Overflow for answers and someone said that old C compilers don't let you declare and initialize variables in the same block, but I don't think that is the problem, because when I comment out the lines

```
m->columns = numColumns(s);
m->rows = numRows(s);
m->data = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * (m->rows * m->columns));
```

all of the syntax errors go away and I have no idea why. Any help is appreciated.

---EDIT----
The code for Matrix was requested

```
typedef struct {
    int rows;
    int columns;
    double *data;
}Matrix;
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the three lines you tried commenting out to below your variable definitions, e.g. after `int numDec;` ?

Comment: Your `class Matrix { ... };` definition is followed by a semicolon, right?

Comment: You need to show more code.  What is Matrix?

Comment: Are you compiling this as C or C++? MSVC tends to default to C++ even for .c files

Comment: I added the code for my Matrix struct, and I'm fairly confident it's being compiled as C because when I Build Solution I get warnings like "warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data" and the "C4244" part makes me think C.

Comment: @Personofblah nope, the leading C on that means compiler, not C language. However because Dukeling's answer worked that answers the question anyway, as in C++ that would not have been the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C compilers not compliant with C99 (i.e. Microsoft Visual C++ 2010) (thanks to [Mgetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332733/mgetz) for pointing this out), you can't declare variables in the middle of a block.

So try moving the variable declarations to the top of the block:

```
void LoadValues(char *s, Matrix *m){
    int counter = 0;
    double temp;
    bool decimal;
    int numDec;
    m->columns = numColumns(s);
    m->rows = numRows(s);
    m->data = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * (m->rows * m->columns));
    while(*s != '\0'){
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dukeling thanks, that worked perfectly! And yeah when I read that post I took that as saying you couldn't do "int counter = 0;" in one line you needed to break it up like "int counter; counter = 0;". 

Thanks again!